# use Cufon font in fpdf

Tags: php, fonts, fpdf, cufon

I'm using **FPDF** to create pdf. I need to insert image with Cufon font. I'm having cufon font in **.js** format. I [read out](http://www.fpdf.org/) , and i applied like,

```
<?php
require('makefont/makefont.php');

MakeFont('c:\\Windows\\Fonts\\comic.ttf','cp1252');
?>
```

No use. I need help.

font.js is like,

```
Cufon.registerFont({"w":168,"face":{"font-family":"BankScript","font-weight":400,"font-stretch":"normal","units-per-em":"360","panose-1":"2 0 5 6 0 0 0 2 0 4"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm ignorant, but what is a font in .js format ?

Comment: To my knownledge, PDF has nothing todo with HTML or JS. You can however embed TrueType Fonts into it and use them. Has nothing todo with Cufon at all, which is a JS/CSS Technology.